# How to use chumper datatable to show values from array

Tags: php, arrays, datatable, laravel-5

I have to read names of the files present in some specific folder in laravel package (from resources/lang folder to check available languages) and then show these names in the datatable. I am able to read the names of available folders in resources/lang using scandir($directory) and I am storing these names in an array. I am using chumper datatable and I have to show these array values in that table. But I can not do that because I don't know how to populate chumper datatable without using database query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I'd solved the problem I was facing.
To use custom array to populate values in your chumper datatable you have to create a new Eloquent::collection.

Use the CollectionEngine and create a new Collection:

Datatable::collection(new Collection(your array))->...

and then you'll be able to use your table.